# How to clearsign and encrypt in go using openpgp

Tags: go, encryption, rsa, pgp

My goal is to use read a PEM file (which contains a private key) and a passphrase to clearsign a file and then use openpgp to encrypt it using a public key that has been provided to me.

I know I should use `block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pemFile))` to read the file and the `ParsePKCS1PrivateKey` but I am not sure how to clear sign the file using the key and the passphrase and then encrypt the signed using `golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp`

Reading the pem file and creating a private key is straightforward:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("myPemFile")
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(data))
key, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
```

where the key is `*rsa.PrivateKey`. The question is how to use a passphrase and the private key to clear sign a file i.e. doing something equivalent to:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-file <passfile> --clearsign <unsigned file>
```